# Listener/Observer Model in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, mvc, php5

I've taken a look at the SPL Listener/Observer model but found that it doesn't work when using static methods. So I wrote my own but it's very simply.  Can anyone suggest ways to make it more like the Model standards and if there is anything obvious that I've missed?

```
<?php
namespace modular\core;

class Listeners{
    private static $listeners = array();
    private static $triggered = array();
    private static $broadcasts = array();

    public static function attach($event, $key, $callback){
        $config = \modular\core\ModuleLoader::getModuleConfig($key);
        $config['instance'] = get_class($callback[0]);
        $callback['config'] = $config;
        static::$listeners[$event][md5($event.$key)] = array('module' => $key, 'callback' => $callback);
    }

    public static function detach($event, $key, $callback){
        unset(static::$listeners[$event][md5($event.$key)]);
    }

    public static function listeners($event = ''){
        return ($event == '') ? static::$listeners : static::$listeners[$event];
    }

    public static function listenersRegistered(){
        return static::$listeners;
    }

    public static function listenersTriggered(){
        return static::$triggered;
    }

    public static function getBroadcasts(){
        return static::$broadcasts;
    }

    public static function broadcast($event){
        $rendered = \modular\core\Renderer::rendered();

        $caller = debug_backtrace();//true, 1 - check version and implement this
        array_shift($caller);

        static::$broadcasts[$event][] = $caller;

        if(isset(static::$listeners[$event])){
            if(!$rendered)
                ob_start();

            foreach(static::$listeners[$event] as $listener){
                $myEvent = (\modular\core\Router::routed() ? ($listener['module'] == \modular\core\ModuleLoader::getActiveModule()) : true);
                if($myEvent){
                    static::$triggered[$event] = $listener;
                    $test = \modular\core\ModuleLoader::runModule($listener);
                }
            }

            if(!$rendered)
                ob_end_clean();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The code to add a listener:

```
public static function addListener($event, $callback){
        $modules = \modular\core\ModuleLoader::getModules();

        if(($key = array_search($callback[0], $modules)) !== false){
            \modular\core\Listeners::attach($event, $key, $callback);
        }
        else{
            //problem - object not found...
        }
    }

_::addListener('pre-render', array(&$this, 'init'));
```

Callback is a callback function set as an array to specify the instance

The MD5 is used to combine both the `$event` and `$key` as a `$key` (module) can register to multiple events and vice-versa.

Broadcast is purely checking if any output has already occurred, if not then block all output if so then allow output whilst it calls the module callback method.

Because it's a framework static methods are used as my preferred method to access a class from multiple classes without having to worry about creating variables of instances that I either have to remember globally or re-instantiating the class constantly.

Comment: Question (maybe its just me but i want to help you out): are you asking to turn your static class into a more traditional OOP class since you are using too many static classes?

Comment: @azngunit81 given that the *Observer Pattern* and *design patterns* in general are something that makes *elements of reusable **object-oriented** software*, I think an answer that approaches the OP's code from an OOP perspective would be very much valuable.

Comment: @Mat'sMug right which is why before I started to chop his code up and render it as OOP I just wanted to know if thats what he wanted because in his edit he likes static methods but what he describes can be remedy by using a SOLID approach and have the D part handle with a IoC so that he doesn't need to worry about redefining classes so much

Answer (score 8):

> *Because it's a framework static methods are used as my preferred method to access a class from multiple classes without having to worry about creating variables of instances that I either have to remember globally or re-instantiating the class constantly.*

I don't do [php](/questions/tagged/php), but I'll give this one a try.

*Being a framework* shouldn't be a reason to prefer `static` methods everywhere.

The *Observer Pattern* can be depicted as follows:

[image: Observer pattern]

> *I've taken a look at the SPL Listener/Observer model but found that it doesn't work when using static methods.*

There's a reason for that. If I read the code correctly, then when you have a class called `SubjectA`, and register 3 observers statically, *every single instance* of `SubjectA` will have the 3 observers registered; this is unlikely to be the intended behavior (not to mention threading issues), and it's only happening because of the `static` stuff.<sup>1</sup>

It looks like your `Listeners` class is intended to be used in *object composition*, like, you'll create a `Car` class that *has a* `Listeners` instance, and you'll register listeners for an `Explode` event. Then you might have a `Dog` class that *has a*[nother] `Listeners` instance, and you'll register listeners for a `Bark` event. If I assessed the situation correctly, that will give you a barking `Car` and an exploding `Dog`, on top of the expected events.

<sub><sup>1</sup> that is, if `static` in [php](/questions/tagged/php) has the same meaning as `static` in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), which I'm assuming here.</sub>

Comment: I'm always surprise when my car barks!

Answer (score 6):

I see several problems here:

- It's hard to understand your code because you have not documented any of the methods and their arguments. I have trouble understanding what's the purpose of `$event`, `$key` and `$callback` arguments. First off I though that `$callback` must be a the callback function, but from code it looks like it's an array of some sort. What should it contain?
- I don't understand why the `md5()` function is used. Why don't you just index by `$key`?
- The broadcast() seems to be doing some rendering and output buffering. Looks like too many responsibilities for a Listeners class that should be dealing only with event delegation.
- There are static references to several classes like `\modular\core\ModuleLoader`. Which means your Listeners class is very tightly coupled with these. It also doesn't help my understanding of your code, as I don't have access to these classes.
- The fact that you have a need for a static Listeners class feels like a design smell. Too many static methods usually means you aren't really doing proper object-oriented programming, but rather just using classes as containers for your functions. Instead you should consider implementing it as a simple class with normal methods and just instantiating it as a globally available singleton.

Comment: Have edited to clarify, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 5):

`$broadcasts` are just for debugging purposes, right?

My thoughts:

- The name `Listeners` sounds to me like it's an enhanced homogenous collection. Considering a core part is broadcasting I would suggest renaming. I believe Doctrine2 uses name `EventManager`, so maybe something along those lines
- As suggested I would consider moving away from static-ness. You can arguably keep your static method `::addListener()` and have an instance of Listeners as a static property if you really do want to keep the static access.

  But in a well-designed application (where classes have reasonable number of dependencies) handling instances shouldn't be an issue. The class will be more flexible and easier to test (for that matter I wouldn't even recommend the class itself as singleton, having just one instance can be handled as noted above).

  Take a look at *Misko Hevery's Guide: Writing Testable Code* (while individual points are arguable the overall approach is something worth at least considering).
- As also suggested `::broadcast()` probably does more than it should, but I don't have enough understanding of your application to make a suggestion.
- I would rename `::listeners()` to `::getListeners()`, for clarify and for consistency with `::getBroadcasts()`. Same for other `::listeners##()` methods. Somewhat nitpicky would be to suggest usage of `null` over an empty string to mark an empty value
- Don't know if it's only for clarity here, but you keep referencing classes from the same namespace as `Listeners` using their fully qualified name. You can remove all those `\module\core\` as it's all in the same namespace. You may also search for **use** keyword, may come in handy one day.
- You do not have to re-instantiate instances! If you want more parts of application (say classes) to have access to a certain instance you pass the instance to them in some way (like constructor or setter injection) and assign it to a property. (don't worry about passing-by-value as in case of instances PHP actually just passes an object ID, so it is pretty much a reference).
- MD5 is not needed, PHP indexes are already being hashed. Some nice articles:

  - [Understanding PHP's internal array implementation](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html)
  - [Hash algorithm and collisions](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/hashtables/hash_algorithm.html)

Comment: The convention for PHP namespaces is the same for classes: they should be in PascalCase, i.e. `namespace Modular\Core;`

Comment: @CJDennis I don't see how this relates to my answer, would probably be better to post it under the question or as an answer